# Office software remembers logged out person when using FBA

Tags: forms-authentication

I have a SharePoint 2010 site using Forms Based Authentication (ASP.NET Membership)

1. User (A) logon to the SharePoint site.
2. Opens a document for editing in Word.
3. Word displays form for login. User fills out FBA form to login.
4. Checks "Remember me"
5. Edits document and saves.
6. User (A) logs out.
7. User (B) logs in and does the same as user (A). But will not be asked for username/password before editing document. When user (B) saves the "Modified by" are still the user (B).

How can I make sure the "Modified by" field always sets the current user?
Am I missing something in the FBA config?

Comment: What steps does user B repeat? All of them? Do you mean that when user B edits a document on te pc of user A, the document should be "modified" by user A?

Comment: When user B edits the document it should be 'modified' by user B. Now it's beeing modified by user A even if user B is the logged on user. This only occurs when user A logged on first with the 'remember me' option checked.

Comment: I don't think there's something you can do about this in sharepoint. The problem is that your browser is using the password and user that is stored in it. Maybe you can set somewhere in your browser that no username or passwords can be stored?

Comment: By "User (B) logs in" are you referring to the user logging into Windows or simply into the browser?  Also, was Word closed between step 5 and step 7?

Comment: What if you remove SharePoint site from Intranet or Trusted Sites in Internet Options on the Security tab? A manual process would be to remove stored credentials, but accessing this depends on OS you use. If windows 7, type "cred" in Windows search and open credentials manager. From there you can remove saved user credentials. For XP, in the Control Panel open User Profiles, choose your profile and on the left side you have an option to access stored network passwords. (I could be mistaking, because writing from top of my head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All office apps use their own internal browser when requesting files from a web site so that when you are authenticating in Word, you are authenticating Word's internal browser to use that ID.

As long as that instance of Word is running, it doesn't matter who you subsequently log into the website as because Word's internal browser is still using the original credentials provided when Word opened.

to get around the issue you are seeing, you can do any of the following

1. Close Word before logging in as the other user
2. Log into Windows as
       the other user
3. Use different machines to test the different users